# Metrics and dimensions are not showing up for hits of type 'event'

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have a fully functional and working code (written in C#) which purpose is to track some hits to the specified GA property. This code has been tested and still works successfully. It adds some predefined dimensions (like `App Version`) to each hit and a several custom metrics to a certain hit types (like `event` with a certain `Event Action`).

So far so good everything works flawlessly when taking into account the first property to which these hits are being sent. Also everything is fine when I set up a brand new GA property and track my hits to it - that is, I'm able to see events in `Realtime` reports, and events show up in custom reports after a while so that I can see my custom metrics.

The issue is that when I try to send **absolutely the same** hits to the existing property which had been created and configured ages ago - there is no both dimensions (even predefined) and custom metrics in my custom reports. I see these events in realtime and behavior reports, and I'm even able to create a custom report against events count - but that's it. I'm able to use for example `Day of the month` as a primary dimension, but when I try to use `App Version` as a dimension or my custom metrics as report metrics - it says "*There is no data for this view.*".

I've already tried everything I could, have read almost every post about custom definitions in Google and viewed almost each related SO question and answer - still with no luck.

- We use measurement protocol
- There is a correct `User Agent` being sent with each hit
- 17 days has passed since my first attempt to track these hits with existing property
- There is no filters and segments at all
- There is only one view

For me it looks like a property misconfiguration, but I've inspected each configuration page (I have all possible rights granted) and have not found anything related.

Will appreciate any help with this issue.

**UPD: The hit itself (with the sensitive data replaced):**
`t=event&ec=session&ea=connection_end&el=b225d53a-6bb2-8021-f7b5-ae7004ae0a00&cm1=174960&cm2=1751494&cm3=479033&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-X&cid=4119e77f-be87-4530-04d3-33882f8eea77&v=1&av=XX.XX.99.555&an=my-awesome-app&aid=app.awesome.my`

**UPD: Here is what I'm trying to achieve (screenshot was made at the test property, where everything works like a charm):**
[image: Working report by built-int App Version and Day of the Month dimensions]

Comment: do you have bot filtering disabled?

Comment: I've tried to turn it off and on again, still no luck. Have to mention that I can see the hits, count them and so on, but the custom metrics which I'm sending with these hits does not show up - that is, I see zeros only in my reports instead of meaningful values.

Comment: edit your question and add the hit you are sending

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this because of NDA. Can say only that exactly the same hits are tracked successfully (i. e. tracked with metrics - I can build some meaningful reports against them) to 3 other GA properties which I've created for the test purposes. Validator also says that everything is ok - that is, the hit is absolutely correct, there is an issue with property itself. All this information could be found in the question.

Comment: Im not sure that app version can be sent to web properties i suspect that was only for web properties but i cant say i have tried.    Without seeing the hit you are sending its hard to help.

Comment: This is absolutely possible, but additional fields like app name have to be sent as well in order for app version to appear in the reports. I've updated the question with the report screen from the test property - here I use `App Version` and `Day of the Month` as the dimensions.

Comment: I'll post the hits I'm sending later

Comment: Added the hit I'm sending to the question as well

Comment: Did you turn off bot filtering?

Comment: As I've already mentioned before - I've tried to turn it off, have got the same situation. I'm still able to count these events, the issue is that custom metrics does not show up in my custom reports. I guess I shouldn't be able to count events if they are blocked by a bot filter.

Comment: For anyone who is experiencing the same issues - we have not found the proper solution for this issue, thus switched to the fresh (created from scratch) GA property, and everything works like a charm now.